# Estimating parameters and simulating a multivariate time series (O-U?) process

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-regression, stochastic-processes, joint-distribution

Say I have 5 time series that may or may not be correlated with each other. I also suspect they individually may be mean reverting. I'd like to

1) be able to test the hypothesis they are individually mean reverting

2) generate/simulate future hypothetical trajectories based on estimates obtained (taking observed correlations in to account)

3) obtain analytic prediction intervals if possible

For (1) Is the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test appropriate to be run across the time series individually?

For (2) I figure a multivariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process might be appropriate. Is there any easy way to find the parameters across the individual time series, test then generate simulations in such a way that correlations/covariance is taken in to account? That is, obtain the joint distribution of the parameters. Is there a recommended solution/implementation for R? Or am I just better off fitting a vector arima model or something?